# How to read emails from remote Lotus notes 8.5.3 server using PHP

Tags: php, email, lotus-notes, lotus-domino

I am trying to read Lotus notes 8.5.3 emails from a remote server using PHP code.

It looked pretty straight when I read emails from Gmail using below code. But the same code did not connect to Lotus notes though the *remote server* supported POP3 on port 110 
(I'm able to access emails on a web browser, I think that is the Web Access Lite mode)

```
<?php
    class Email_reader {
        // server connection
        public $conn;
        private $server = "{imap.gmail.com:993/imap/ssl/novalidate-cert/norsh}Inbox";
        private $user   = 'xyz@gmail.com';
        private $pass   = '123';

        function __construct() {
            $this->connect();
        }

        function close() {       
            imap_close($this->conn);
        }

        function connect() {
            try {
                $this->conn = imap_open($this->server, $this->user, $this->pass) or die("Can't connect to:'$this->server': " . imap_last_error());
                echo 'If you see this, we got IMAP working';
            }
            catch(Exception $e) {
                echo 'error Message: ' .$e->getMessage();
            }
        }
    }

    $obj = new Email_reader();
    echo "-------------------------00-------------------------";
    $obj->close();
?>
```

I tried diff server url formats in the above code:

{server.com:110/pop3}INBOX

{server.com:110/pop3/novalidate-cert}INBOX

Can someone point me,

- if I'm missing something in the above code
- can I not access Lotus notes emails this way at all? Is so, what is the way to access them from PHP
- If not possible from PHP, I'm open to chose other programming languages, but it has to be from remote server (Linux)
- If there are good references/example code, that would be great

Thanks.

Comment: adding few additional details:

I'm required to read my customer's Lotus notes emails as part of a solution I'm coming up with. This application will be on Linux, an external server and I do not have Lotus notes/Domino installed locally where the application is running.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Domino Web Access Lite does not use POP3. It uses HTTP.

Domino servers can support POP3, but it is not enabled by default and in most cases it probably remains disabled. You will have to talk to your Domino server's administrators in order to see if they are willing to enable it for you. You will probably need a very good reason in order to convince them to do this.

If you are running PHP on a Wndows machine that has Lotus Notes or Domino installed, then you can access Domino data on your server using the Domino COM objects, which is described in this [old article on IBM's web site](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/lotus/library/domino-php/).

Comment: Thanks for your comments. Added a few details that I missed originally..

Will check if I can get POP3 enabled on Lotus notes, which may be unlikely!. Once enabled, should the above code work without any changes? This worked for Gmail as I said before.
also, from the article you pointed out, seems that it is unlikely that I'll be able to talk to Notes email server from remote Linux  without some modifications on the server - such as deploying an agent or additional configurations on the Lotus notes server.

Comment: I don't know anything about how PHP does IMAP, so I don't know if it will work without changes. My guess, though, is that probably will be fine.  You also may have the option of using Domino Data  Service, which is a REST API service. It is available for Domino 8.5.3, and your server admins might be more willing to enable it than POP3. (If I recall correctly, using POP3 on Domino requires updating the template for user mail files, and that's a pretty big deal. The REST API does not need that.)

Comment: The example php- codes uses IMAP, but you talk about POP3. Enabling POP3 on the server side will not help at all with code that runs on the IMAP port. For your code to run you need the domino- admin to run the IMAP task, not the POP3 task

Comment: I ddn't notice that! Pretty obvious, though :-)

Comment: that's correct @TorstenLink; I'm ok with either of them :)
But my main issue is connecting to Lotus notes email server, as it looked diff compared to the other email servers

Comment: @RichardSchwartz, most of the issues I faced were due to policy configurations in Lotus Domino server and also the port being blocked for outside connections.
Also that web access lite is http based client, which was able to connect to the server.
The PHP code above should suffice for connecting to IMAP / POP3 ..
here is the pop URL:

    // $this->server = "{pop.gmail.com:995/pop3/ssl/novalidate-cert}Inbox";

Thanks to all for your inputs ..